# Why does 1 provide a different answer than 2 in this program, for the area in which 1 should be the same?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

I have this code, meant to calculate compound interest with yearly deposits. The problem is, the number in the slot where running the code with 1 in t's place gives me a different answer than when running it with a 2. These should be giving me yearly answers for the total. Below is the code.

```
P = input("Input principal ")
R = input("Input rate ")
T = input("Input time ")
t1 = float(input("Input times per year "))
p = float(P)
r = float(R)
t = float(T)
d = float(input("deposit"))

zed = []
for num in range(int(t) + 1):
    zed.append(num)


# (1 + r/n)
body = 1 + (r / t1)
# nt
exponent = t1 * t
# P(1 + r/n)^nt
re = p * pow(body, exponent)

ked = []
for var in zed:
    body = 1 + (r / t1)
    exponent = t1 * t
    idekvar = (p + (d * var)) * pow(body, exponent)
    ked.append(idekvar)
    print (idekvar)

"""print ("With principal")
print (re)
print ("Without principal")
print (re-p)"""
```

It gives me an output of

> 3.5999999999999996
>   9.6
>   [3.5999999999999996, 9.6]

when I use `p = 3 r = .2 t=1 t1 = 1` and `dep = 5`, it gives me a different answer for, what SHOULD be, the same space, but using `t = 2` instead.

> 4.32
>   11.52
>   18.72
>   [4.32, 11.52, 18.72]

Why does it do this? 
If you happen to have any code that does this, would you mind sharing so I can compare mine to it?

Comment: @RoryDaulton Fixed.

Comment: I don't see why this should produce the same output. After all, you are multiplying the exponent with `t`.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Ok, so I see I would need to multiply by var instead of t. Where do I go from there?

Comment: Are you *sure* that `t=2` should produce the same result? Also: `float`s are **not** real numbers. Maybe this is just an artifact of the inherent approximation errors in using `float`s...

Comment: In your loop you have `body = 1+r/t1` and you never change neither `r` nor `t1`. Are you sure that you didn't want something dependent on `exponent`? Because your code's results **clearly** depend on the value of `t` since in the loop you have `exponent = t1*t` and given that nothing else depends on `t` you *obviously* get different results when changing `t`. You could obtain similar results only if there was something *else* changing based on `t` and thus balancing the change in the exponent...

Comment: @Bakuriu Ok, so I see that. I need to make it to where I can see the previous years interest and deposit (I.E. 340.15) and calculate NEXT years interest using that 340.15. What might you suggest?